# Difference between model.train(False) and required_grad = False

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I use the Pytorch library and i'm looking for a way to make the weights and biases in my model to freeze.

I saw these 2 options:

1. `model.train(False)`
2. `for param in model.parameters(): param.requires_grad = False`

What is the difference (if there is any) and which one should i use to freeze the current state of my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are very different.

Independently of the backprop process, some layers have different behaviors when you are training or evaluating a model. In pytorch, there are only 2 of them : BatchNorm (which I think stops updating its running mean and deviation when you are evaluating) and Dropout (which only drops values in training mode). So `model.train()`and `model.eval()`(equivalently `model.train(false)`) just set a boolean flag to tell these 2 layers "freeze yourselves". Note that these two layers do not have any parameters that are affected by backward operation (batchnorm **buffer** tensors are changed during the forward pass I think)

On the other hand, setting all your parameters to "requires_grad=false" just tells pytorch to stop recording gradients for backprop. That will not affect the BatchNorm and the Dropout layers

How to freeze your model kinda depends on your use-case, but I'd say the easiest way is to use [torch.jit.trace](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.trace.html#torch.jit.trace). This will create a frozen copy your model, exactly in the state it was when you called `trace`. Your model remained unaffected.

Usually, you would call

```
model.eval()
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, input)
```

Comment: It torch.jit.trace reversible? In case i decide i want to train for a few more epochs

Comment: I edited my answer to add clarity. Tracing your model will not affect it, it will just create a frozen copy of it

Comment: BatchNorm does have trainable parameters - new mean and standard deviation. Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are [two ways](https://dejanbatanjac.github.io/2019/11/13/Freezing-layers.html) to freeze in PyTorch when training:

- setting `requires_grad` to `False`
- setting the learning rate lr to zero

While `model.train(False)` is a way not to train. ;)